# MonoDevelop 2.2 beta 2 "No File Name Provided" When Launching in External Console

Tags: c#, console, monodevelop, filenames

When I try to run my Mono C# programs in MonoDevelop on an external console, I get the following error.

http://i146.photobucket.com/albums/r248/bobber205/error.jpg
(First time needing to post a pic here on stackoverflow, sorry if this isn't correct to just post a link)

:)

It runs on windows's regular "cmd" console when I debug with input working as well.

I've tested an older version of mono and this feature worked. (Note I get this error on both Windoows Vista, Windows 7, and Mac OS X).

Any ideas on how to give it that "filename"? I thought maybe beta 2 would fix this but I guess not. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that MonoDevelop uses xterm & bash for the "external console", which won't work on Windows, and might have problems on Mac. It needs to be abstracted out to use native consoles for these different platforms.

Please file a bug: http://monodevelop.com/Developers#Reporting_Bugs

Comment: I remember this working on 2.0 or an earlier version on OS X.

Comment: I just checked, and it works fine on OS X for me. Maybe you don't have X11 installed?